# how to run a Initialization Script to create vm in the oracle oci java sdk

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In the Oracle OCI web console, when you try to create a new compute instance, the console allows you to upload a Initialization Script to run some of the setup command automatically.
how to achieve the same benefit from the oci java sdk?

Comment: Check the https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/java/1.17.4/com/oracle/bmc/core/model/InstanceConfigurationLaunchInstanceDetails.html metadata for `user_data`.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an OCI VM, you can set its metadata to include an initialization script. Take a look at the example on how to set instance metadata as part of instance launch [here](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/CreateInstanceExample.java#L791). To specify an initialization script as part of the metadata, you'll want to set the key `user_data` in the metadata, with the value described as mentioned [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/java/1.17.4/com/oracle/bmc/core/model/LaunchInstanceDetails.html#getMetadata--) (see "user_data" section).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly once i upload the config file into the user_data?

Comment: Anther question for Always Free ATP:I plan to use the Oci java Sdk to create an always free ATP instance in the Oracle OCI environment.
Check with the examples bundled with oci java sdk and API. It lack details for the Always free ATP docs.
like to know 
 - which class can be used？
 - ssh public key required? as from web console, not necessary to give the SSH public key during the creation procedure
 - which database edition can be used for Always free?

are the Always free ATP example available?

Thank you so much.